# NSTImer Getting paused in background in iphone 5

Tags: iphone, nstimer

i have developed an app which is running fine in background since i am using `GPS` service.In the

app `NSTimer` is also running fine in background  in `IPhone 4` and `IPhone 4s`.

how ever it is getting pause in `IPhone5` when app is in background.

the code i am using for `NSTimer` is

```
repeatTimer5 =   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target: self
                                                        selector: @selector(toupdate) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];


 [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]addTimer:repeatTimer5 forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

has any one faced the same issue?

Comment: NSTimer doesn't work in background.,,

Comment: its working in background since i am using location service in app so its working fine ..how ever it is getting pause in iphone5

Comment: Fire this timer in delegate method of AppDelegate:
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   //fire timer
}

Comment: Are you using the same versions of iOS on the iPhone 4/4S and the iPhone 5?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :
Fire your timer when app  did entered into background in AppDelegate delegate method:

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        if(!repeatTimer5.isValid)
        {
repeatTimer5 =   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target: self
                                                                 selector: @selector(toupdate) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
        }


    }

    - (void)toupdate
    {
        DLog(@"Testing timer Fired");
    }
```

this will fire your timer method when app moved in foreground and will resumed when app moved in background.

If you still need to this timer will be fired in background mode then start BackgroundTask

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        if(!repeatTimer5.isValid)
         {
       [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        //your background expiration handler method
    }];

    repeatTimer5 =   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target: self
                                                             selector: @selector(toupdate) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
          }


    }

    - (void)toupdate
    {
        DLog(@"Testing timer Fired");
    }
```

This will fire your timer when ur app is in background

Comment: if the timer has ran for 3 second and user press the home button so in did enter again he need to calculate or again fire for 5 second.seems that not a valid solution.

Comment: see my edited ans. this works fine for me. and for every time u need to check is ur timer is valid or not.

Comment: Also add a check for timer is valid or not. If ur timer is valid it doesnt start timer. else it will schedule a timer

Comment: no i have to continously run the timer in the app weather its in background or foreground.

Comment: Please see my complete ans i had already explained for background timer in next solution
use "beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler" for continously running ur timer in background as well as foreground